# Three.js addon for Blender not showing in Addons screen (on windows 7 and Windows Vista)

Tags: windows, plugins, three.js, blender, add-on

Has anyone been able to get the `three.js` import export addon for `Blender` to work on `Windows 7` or `Windows Vista`

I tried on two different computers.

On `windows 7` I placed the files in (I have blender `2.65` on this machine)
`E:\blender-2.65-release-windows32\blender-2.65-release-windows32\2.65\scripts\addons\io_mesh_threejs`

On Windows Vista where I have blender 2.66 I placed the files in 
`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.66\scripts\addons`

I looked in the User Preferences and can not see the addon there. I also tried the filter etc.

Comment: See the following error if I start blender from command line

fake_module: addon missing 'bl_info' gives bad performance!: 'C:\BlenderInstall
\Blender2.66\2.66\scripts\addons\io_mesh_threejs\__init__.py'

Comment: Figured out the problem.

Comment: I was saving the .py files using file save on github from the browser. This added HTML tags to the .py files which it did not like. Instead go to the RAW tab on github copy text and save as .py and everything starts to work

Answer (score 0):

You can put the files on the Windows 7 system as the same directory as you did for the Vista one - `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.xx\scripts\addons`
Inside that directory create a folder named, `io_mesh_threejs`. Put the files inside there.

When you grab the files from github, make sure you view the Raw version then you can 'Save As' from your browser.

Similarly, if using `wget`, make sure it is the raw version of the file so you don't download the file with html content.